# Render dynamic value inside content django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Please, I would like to render a varible in django template, kind of `{{ user.name }}` inside of a textfield from database, that I filled up on the django admin. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyGbj.png)

how can I manage to achieve it please, thank you all, have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of looking, I found out that the right solution of accomplishing such a thing is by creating a filter or tag and affecting it to the content rendered from the database based on the Django documentation link to [create custom filters and tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/), I created a filter that takes the content as a variable and scanned whenever I find the variable I replace it with the content from the database

```
# This code goes in the filter logic

values = model.objects.all()
content.replace('{{ user.name }}',values.name)


# This is how the content is rendered on the template

{{content | filter_name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom form then try using

```
value={{ user.name }}
```

and if you are letting Django render the form for you as like `"form.as_p"` then you can try

```
form_instance = Form(request.POST)
```

and send the form instance to the template